# google actions: suggestion chips in SignIn

Tags: actions-on-google

When using google actions sdk, as per documentation, we achieve it via such a code

```
app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});
```

Is there a way to add suggestion chips such as `Yes` and `No`. Thanks

Comment: No you can't add suggestions during this request